# Function to get yesterday's date in Javascript in format DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, date

I've been looking for a while to get yesterday's date in format DD/MM/YYYY.
Here's my current code:

```
var $today = new Date();
var $dd = $today.getDate();
var $mm = $today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var $yyyy = $today.getFullYear();
if($dd<10){$dd='0'+dd} if($mm<10){$mm='0'+$mm} $today = $dd+'/'+$mm+'/'+$yyyy;
```

With this, I get today's date in format DD/MM/YYYY (thanks SO).
But when I try this:

```
var $yesterday = $today.getDate()-1;
```

as recommended on this site somewhere else (lost the link), I get an error saying that getDate() was not found for this object.

I'm using my script with Sahi, but I don't think it's linked, as Sahi has no trouble with Javascript.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would this be better: http://jsfiddle.net/LZLgN/ ? Of course you'll have to fill necessary `0`s.

Comment: It's because your `$today` was finally assigned to a string (`"dd/mm/yyyy"`), and a string do not have method `getDate()`.

Comment: Why all the awkward `$`? It's not PHP, you know.

Comment: Just FYI, there's a great library to handle Date manipulation: [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Comment: this wont work on 1st Jan, following would: `function getYesterdayDate() {
    let yesterday = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    let arr = [];
    arr.push(yesterday.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + yesterday.getDate() : yesterday.getDate());
    arr.push(yesterday.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (yesterday.getMonth() + 1) : yesterday.getMonth() + 1);
    arr.push(yesterday.getFullYear());
    return arr.join('-');
}`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that you're reassigning `$today` by assigning a string to it:

```
$today = $dd+'/'+$mm+'/'+$yyyy;
```

Strings don't have `getDate`.

Also, `$today.getDate()-1` just gives you the day of the month minus one; it doesn't give you the full date of 'yesterday'. Try this:

```
$today = new Date();
$yesterday = new Date($today);
$yesterday.setDate($today.getDate() - 1); //setDate also supports negative values, which cause the month to rollover.
```

Then just apply the formatting code you wrote:

```
var $dd = $yesterday.getDate();
var $mm = $yesterday.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var $yyyy = $yesterday.getFullYear();
if($dd<10){$dd='0'+$dd} if($mm<10){$mm='0'+$mm} $yesterday = $dd+'/'+$mm+'/'+$yyyy;
```

Because of the last statement, `$yesterday` is now a `String` (**not** a `Date`) containing the formatted date.

Comment: Thank you. Does this method work for every day of the year?

Comment: @user1881815, I'm pretty sure it will. I tested it for the first day of the year, the first day of a month, and the current date, and it worked in those cases.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
function getYesterdaysDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
    return date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, almost there, I just need the zeros to appear before the single numbers. :)

Comment: @user1881815:

Try this

    date.getFullYear() + '/'+ (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;

Comment: This won’t work at on 1st January.

Answer (score 3):

You override `$today` in the if statement.

```
if($dd<10){$dd='0'+dd} if($mm<10){$mm='0'+$mm} $today = $dd+'/'+$mm+'/'+$yyyy;
```

It is then not a Date() object anymore - hence the error.